Excel VBA conditional formatting for certain columns only
I have a table with prices for products. For each product there is one row. For each row there are columns for several companies. Each company has 2 columns - one for old price and one for new price. So if there are 3 companies, there are 6 columns for each product.
I am using conditional formatting for each product row, independent of prices on other rows. The macro I have works (after I add conditional formatting to the first row manually).
But I now need the conditional formatting to ignore the old price columns and add it only to new price columns. Old price columns are usually hidden. If I only add conditional formatting to the new price columns and run the macro, it considers all prices for all products together, not each row individually anymore.
My current code:
Sub NewCF()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim table As Range
Set table = Range("B4", "G8")
Range("B3:G3").Copy
For Each Row In table.Rows
Row.PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)
Next Row
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Is there a way to achieve the desired end result as illustrated on the picture?
I've tried many different ways, read many forum posts but so far no luck.


What's your conditional formatting rule(s)?

What's the problem with looping through and putting separate conditionals on Column C, then Column E, then Column G?

@ChrisMaurer While OP has not provided their Format Conditions for us to confirm, it looks like they are using a Colour Scale on each row.  This will take the Maximum and Minimum values for the target range, and then set the cell colour based on where it falls in that range.  If you did it on a column-basis instead, then the New Price for Product A/Company 3 would drop from being Maximum for the Row (Red) to 50% of the Column (Orange); and Product D would jump from 50% of the Row (Orange) to Maximum of the Column (Red)

@Chronocidal Yes exactly, I am using the Colour Scale on each row and the issue would be exactly as you describe.

You will need a separate rule for every row so that the color scale can be calculated for every row individually.
If you copy and paste the conditional formatting, the formatting will not create a new rule but change the existing rule so that it is valid for the whole range. So copy&paste will fail.
The following procedure will create such a rule for a single row. Just adjust the value of the last column when you have more than 3 customers:
Sub SetPriceFormatting(ws As Worksheet, row As Long)
    With ws
        ' Generate the Range with all cells that need formatting
        Dim r As Range, col As Long
        Set r = ws.Cells(row, 3)
        For col = 5 To 7 Step 2     ' Adjust to the number of companies
            Set r = Union(r, Cells(row, col))
        Next col
    End With
   
    With r
        ' Remove existing FCs
        Dim fc As Object
        For Each fc In r.FormatConditions
            fc.Delete
        Next fc
         
        ' Create Color Scale Formatting and set color properties.
        Set fc = r.FormatConditions.AddColorScale(ColorScaleType:=2)
        With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(1)
            .Type = xlConditionValueLowestValue
            .FormatColor.Color = vbGreen
            .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        
        With fc.ColorScaleCriteria(2)
            .Type = xlConditionValueHighestValue
            .FormatColor.Color = vbRed
            .FormatColor.TintAndShade = 0
        End With
    End With
End Sub

A routine to set individual FCs for every existing row of sheet 1 (except the header row), use the following code. Again, adjust the worksheet so that it works on the sheet with your price data.
Sub SetAllPriceFormattin()    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)     ' Adjust to your sheet
    Dim row As Long, lastrow As Long
    lastrow = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    For row = 2 To lastrow
        SetPriceFormatting ws, row
    Next
End Sub


Option Explicit

Sub NewCF()

    Dim n
    With Range("B3")
        For n = 1 To 6 Step 2
            .Offset(0, n).Copy
            .Offset(1, n).Resize(5).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        Next
    End With
End Sub

